# The destruction of the Second Temple in the Mishnah?

Tags: beis-hamikdash, mishna, churban-destruction

Is there any explicit mention of the destruction of the Second Temple within the Mishnah specifically? If so, examples of passages? If not, why wouldn't such a momentous occasion be discussed within the Mishnah?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [Sefaria search](https://www.sefaria.org/search?q=%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%97%D7%A8%D7%91&tab=text&tpathFilters=Mishnah&tvar=1&tsort=chronological&svar=1&ssort=relevance) shows that the phrase "משחרב בית המקדש" - "From when the Temple was destroyed..." appears in seven Mishnayot:

Mishnah Maaser Sheni 5:2

> רַבִּי יוֹסֵי אוֹמֵר, מִשֶּׁחָרַב בֵּית הַמִּקְדָּשׁ, הָיָה הַתְּנַאי
> הַזֶּה. וּתְנַאי הָיָה, אֵימָתַי שֶׁיִּבָּנֶה בֵּית הַמִּקְדָּשׁ,
> יַחֲזֹר הַדָּבָר לִכְמוֹת שֶׁהָיָה:

Mishnah Sukkah 3:12

> מִשֶּׁחָרַב בֵּית הַמִּקְדָּשׁ, הִתְקִין רַבָּן יוֹחָנָן בֶּן זַכַּאי
> שֶׁיְּהֵא לוּלָב נִטָּל בַּמְּדִינָה שִׁבְעָה, זֵכֶר לַמִּקְדָשׁ.
> וְשֶׁיְּהֵא יוֹם הָנֵף כֻּלּוֹ אָסוּר:

Mishnah Moed Katan 3:6

> רַבִּי אֱלִיעֶזֶר אוֹמֵר, מִשֶּׁחָרַב בֵּית הַמִּקְדָּשׁ, עֲצֶרֶת
> כְּשַׁבָּת. רַבָּן גַּמְלִיאֵל אוֹמֵר, רֹאשׁ הַשָּׁנָה וְיוֹם
> הַכִּפּוּרִים, כָּרְגָלִים.

Mishnah Nazir 5:4

> וּמִשֶּׁחָרַב בֵּית הַמִּקְדָּשׁ, אֵינוֹ נָזִיר:

Mishnah Sotah 9:12

> מִשֶּׁחָרַב בֵּית הַמִּקְדָּשׁ, בָּטַל הַשָּׁמִיר וְנֹפֶת צוּפִים,
> וּפָסְקוּ אַנְשֵׁי אֲמָנָה, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר הוֹשִׁיעָה ה' כִּי גָמַר
> חָסִיד וְגוֹ'.

Mishnah Sotah 9:15

> רַבִּי פִנְחָס בֶּן יָאִיר אוֹמֵר, מִשֶּׁחָרַב בֵּית הַמִּקְדָּשׁ,
> בּוֹשׁוּ חֲבֵרִים וּבְנֵי חוֹרִין, וְחָפוּ רֹאשָׁם, וְנִדַּלְדְּלוּ
> אַנְשֵׁי מַעֲשֶׂה, וְגָבְרוּ בַעֲלֵי זְרוֹעַ וּבַעֲלֵי לָשׁוֹן, וְאֵין

Mishnah Menachot 10:5

> מִשֶּׁחָרַב בֵּית הַמִּקְדָּשׁ, הִתְקִין רַבָּן יוֹחָנָן בֶּן זַכַּאי,
> שֶׁיְּהֵא יוֹם הָנֵף כֻּלּוֹ אָסוּר.